# I cannot pass the id to the controller?

Tags: codeigniter-3

I tried to play the songs and pass the dynamic id to the controller.But I tried this code.

```
 <?php 
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($view as $row)
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$i."</td>";
        echo "<td>"."<a href='<?php echo base_url();?>admin/play/$row->audio'".$row->audio."</a></td>";

        $i++;
        echo "</tr>";
    }
   ?>
```

In inspecting the element  anchor shows the direct php code instead of localhost/bla/bla/ how can i fix this? my controller name is play and i want to pass the value of its the particular name.Is my concatenation is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are opening php tags twice. make it like this:

```
<?php 
$i = 1;
foreach ($view as $row)
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$i."</td>";

    echo "<td><a href='" . base_url('admin/play' . $row->audio) . "'>" . $row=>audio . "</a><td>";

    $i++;
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: but it shows the url like this http://localhost/mms/admin/playvanilla%20twilight%20.mp3 is there a problem because the file name consist of the space...?the name of the file is vanilla twilight.mp3.@Tpojka

Comment: Use `urldecode()` function. Check in [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) also.